# jqm 1.1.0 closing dialogs when hashListeningEnabled=false

Tags: jquery-mobile

i've got a page that displays a dialog on an href. am setting **hashListeningEnabled=false** because if someone refreshes the page, they need to be greeted with the first 'page' again. when the dialog is clicked it comes up fine, clicking the close button however does nothing - it changes the href (via **history.back()**), but as listening is disabled, it doesn't actually close the dialog.

anyone think of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that'd be right - as soon as i post the question on SO, i work it out myself. you simply turn **hashListeningEnabled** on when the dialog is shown, then you can turn it back off.